# Discover Meteor chapter 13 sorting algorithm not working properly

Tags: meteor

I'm just starting with meteor (and programming) and I am having problems with the sorting in Chapter 13 (Upvoting).
It should sort the to 5 pages based on the number of votes. Currently the sort order is:

1. 2 votes
2. 2 votes
3. 1 vote
4. 2 votes
5. 2 votes

I already tried debugging, but still failing miserably because I cannot figure out where the query is built and where it is executed.
So I would still have problems pinpointing to where to problematic code is.
I have a github repository where my current state is available.
[Personal Github 13-5](https://github.com/sebastianjonas/microscope/commit/f319f4bf7bf26b451ff33640ec1298e08f12bdb4)

[Offical discovermeteor github commit](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/chapter13-5)

It would be great if someone could pinpoint me to where I should look, how to debug it or what line(s) are problematic.

Comment: Please don't point to outside code. Instead, please copy and paste the code that is *relevant* for this question into the question itself. Thank you. Also, people don't usually like simply debugging your code for you, so please narrow down the question as much as possible.

Comment: Thx for the clue. But as I mentioned in the question, I do not have enough experience to tell where the problem lies.
Anyway. I found the problem. It had a template helper (without the correct parameters) which was used instead of the find method I created in the router.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the clue. But as I mentioned in the question, I do not have enough experience to tell where the problem lies. Anyway. I found the problem. It had a template helper (without the correct parameters) which was used instead of the find method I created in the router.